# How does azure memory usage work?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc

I have a windows azure website. In the dashboard it shows me that I have used 1.51 GB of the 2GB available per hour. I keep increasing the number of instances available in the shared node so the site doesn't shut down. After each hour finishes, the memory usage still shows 1.51 GB used. I assume this would start at ZERO and then be used as time goes on, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

How does server memory work? What are some reasons my application using this much memory? (I use no output caching and generally have just built off of the basic MVC templates provided in visual studio.) What other considerations should I be making to get the amount of memory needed to decrease?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's just the memory footprint that your application is consuming to keep it resident in memory running and ready to respond. It wouldn't go to zero unless it was stopped. From the way your question was phrased is sounds like you're expecting it to be a consumption meter like bandwidth.

As far as why it's using so much memory, that's most likely because you've increased the number of instances that are running and if you dropped it down to one you'd see what the actual footprint was. Then you could dig deeper into optimizing it further with things like caching, etc.

Does that help?